# Why modin.pandas takes more wall time than pandas?

Tags: pandas, bigdata, dataframe

All data scientist know that to scale the pandas to large dataset, we use **modin.pandas** instead of **pandas**. But when I tried to load a 500 MB csv dataset in my jupyter notebook in Ubuntu 16.04 to compare the performance of modin.pandas and simple pandas , it gives unexpected time duration of execution.

**Simple pandas is taking less time, while modin.pandas is taking more time. Why?**

**Code:**

```
import time
import pandas
%%time
# a=time.time()
pandas_csv_data = pandas.read_csv("order_products__prior.csv")
# print(time.time()-a)
```

---

```
import modin.pandas as pd
%%time
# a=time.time()
modin_csv_data =pd.read_csv("order_products__prior.csv")
# print(time.time()-a)
```

Below is the screenshot of code and its corresponding output.
[image: Pandas]
[image: modin import]
[image: modin]

Comment: How many cores are you running on?

Comment: 4 cores, Linux Ubuntu 16.04, 4GB RAM, 1TB hard disk.